# Rollback XCode 4.4 to XCode 4.3

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, nslog

I installed XCode 4.4 on my Snow Leopard machine, but I have a lot of NSLog output, which is just literally freezing up my development with constant beachballs.  It's completely unusable, in my opinion, see this [open radar 11972490](http://openradar.appspot.com/11972490)

Is there any way to rollback to XCode 4.3?  Will it have consequences on my projects?

Comment: Xcode 4.2 is the latest that supports Snow Leopard.  Xcode is a self-contained App; rollback means moving the existing one to trash and copying-over the new one.

Comment: OOps, youre right.  Sorry, I made a mistake.  I'm on Lion! :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To roll Xcode back to a previous version just login to the developer portal and download the particular version of Xcode you want [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode)

Unless you've decided to implement some of the new objective-c features then you should be fine to roll back to 4.3.

Comment: I had the best luck with this solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you indicate, a lot of people have reported your problem, however the solution reported here seems to work for me.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4140838?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Oh sorry @trojanfoe I read your question in haste and missed that. I was previously on Snow Leopard (yesterday morning) and had XCode 4.4 installed and running fine. Then after installing Mountain Lion (yesterday) I had the XCode crash problems, and henve the previoulsy posted link seemed to sort me out.